# Ternary operator on arrays in python

Tags: python, arrays

I am trying to perform the following operation on an array in python:

```
if true then a else b
```

I am trying to perform it on one channel of an image. Basically I want to check if a value is greater than 255, if so, return 255 else return the value that is being checked.

here is what I'm trying:

```
imfinal[:,:,1] = imfinal[:,:,1] if imfinal[:,:,1] <= 255 else 255
```

I get the following error:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Is there a better way to perform this operation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `np.where`:

```
imfinal[:,:,1] = np.where(imfinal[:,:,1] <= 255, imfinal[:,:,1], 255)
```

As to why you get that error see this: [ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062954/valueerror-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-is-ambiguous).

Essentially it becomes ambiguous when you compare arrays using `and`, `or` because what if 1 value in the array matches? To compare arrays you should use bitwise operators `&`, `|`, `~` for `and`, `or`, `not` respectively.

`np.where` uses the boolean condition to assign the value in the second param when true, else assigns the 3rd param, see the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

Answer (score 2):

in your expression:

```
if imfinal[:,:,1] <= 255
```

you're trying to compare a scalar with a vector, so it's unlikely to work.

What you actually want is to use `map()` to do the check on each element of the array:

```
map(lambda x: x if x <= 255 else 255, imfinal[:,:,1])
```

Comment: Looks like map works a lot like the point function. I was curious if it would work anyway when comparing a scalar with a  vector because certain operations of that sort are possible for e.g. imfinal = 1 * (imfinal < 128)

Answer (score 2):

While the other answers cover the general case well, the best solution in your case is probably to use `numpy.minimum` that does the expansion of the scalar for you:

```
imfinal[:,:,1] = numpy.minimum(imfinal[:,:,1], 255)
```

Comment: Perhaps you mean min. OP wants the 255 to be the largest value, not the smallest in the resulting array.

Comment: This introduces the same problem I had earlier

Answer (score 0):

As alternative to using `np.where`

```
mask = imfinal[:,:,1] > 255
imfinal[:,:,1][mask] = 255
```

Or for this specific circumstance (assuming the minimum value allowed is 0).

```
np.clip(imfinal[:,:,1], 0, 255, out=imfinal[:,:,1])
```